# How to display two type data in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

heLLO i have two object in array in my generic component

```
listData() {
      let dataCode = Object.entries(this.data);
      let dataList = {};
      for (let [id, item] of dataCode) {
        if (data.skuId === null) {
          dataList[id] = {
            name: item.name,
            priceProduct: item.price
            productId: favoris.id
          };
        } else {
          dataList[id] = {
            size: item.attributes.size,
            priceSku: item.sellPriceCustomer,
            skuId: item.id
          };
        }
      }
      return dataList;
    }
//result 
listData = [{skuid:234, priceSku:56$, size: M}, {productId: 123, name: bed, priceProduct: 34$, skuId: null}]
```

How to display this array object in one generic component child (i send the props) i add the `v-if` in all a template i don't no is is the best way to that  like this

```
 <span v-if="name !== ''" class="text-bold">{{ name }}</span>
          <span v-if="size !== ''"> size: {{ size }}</span>
          <span v-if="skuId !== null" class="text-bold">{{ priceSku }} €</span>
          <span v-if="productId !== null" class="text-bold"
            >{{ priceProduct }} €</span
          >
```

Please help

Comment: Instead of **size !== ''** you ca use **!!size**, the same for the others, and ya, it is not the best way because your generic component should not know about **size, skuId, ...**. If you send all **listData** as props, then you should just iterate through it with **Object.entries(listData)**

Comment: Sorry, not **Object.entries(listData)**, but **v-for"(item, i) in listData" :key="'item'+i"**